# OpenCV for Android: Error Program "sh" not found in PATH

Tags: java, android, c++, eclipse, opencv

I tried to build `OpenCV4Android SDK` in Eclipse, using the official tutorial [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html). I followed all those instructions, and while trying to build those OpenCV library projects from OpenCV4Android SDK, I got this error:

```
Invoking autoreconf in build directory: C:/Android-64/Opencv4Android/sdk/java/


Configuration failed with error
(sh -c "autoreconf -i" 
Cannot run program "sh": Launching failed

Error: Program "sh" not found in PATH
PATH=[C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2013a\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IDM Computer Solutions\UltraEdit\]
)
```

This is the first time I am trying to build a C++ code in Eclipse (previously I used VS), so I doubt this might be a problem of compiling C++ code in Eclipse. After some internet search, I've turned on the `PE Windows Parser` in `Properties->C/C++Build->Settings->Binary Parsers` in Eclipse, but the error still remains. How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/_images/eclipse_cdt_cfg4.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try installing CYGWIN, and provide the path to the bin directory of cygwin in PATH inside Environment Variable of Windows (before the declaration of Windows Toolkit). Maybe the Windows Toolkit is not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/369435/) you should try creating a new project `Executable project` and then choose the toolchain you want to use.

Comment: Yes, I've also read that thread before asking here. The problem still remains after tried as suggested on that page.